# Reversed silk screening on EasyEDA

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, eda, silkscreen

Just a quick one. I'm not sure if the text should be mirrored on the bottom layer of EasyEDA. It seems okay in the 3D preview, but when I upload the gerber to JLC their preview shows it still reversed. What gives?

[image]

I threw this layout together, and have since realised it can be done on a single layer :P

Comment: Is the text on the bottom of the PCB? And is that where you want it? Components on top?

Comment: Have you followed their recommendation on their Capabilities Page?

Comment: @Tyler thanks for the pointers. Yes the GND VCC IN H1 and OUT text is on the BottomSilkLayer and is reversed correctly, I just wasn't sure if it would print inverted because the preview of the gerber on JLC shows that it will.